# How to improve the performance of this query that spans across multiple databases?

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008

here is my query taking nearly 20 mins. pls suggest me changes to increase performance

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CONVERT(varchar(10),x.notice_date,120)  Date,
    Y.branch_name,
    count(case when x.status='broken' and x.branch_name=y.branch_name then 1 end) 
      Broken,
    count(case when x.type='Lote' and x.branch_name=y.branch_name then 1 end)
      Lost,
    (   SELECT COUNT(A.car_no)
        FROM DB2.dbo.z_mat A
        WHERE DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0,a.notice_date), 0)
              = DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0,x.notice_date), 0)
          AND a.branch_name=y.branch_name
    ) mat,
    (   SELECT COUNT(B.car_no)
        FROM DB2.dbo.z_cat B
        WHERE DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0,b.notice_date), 0)
              = DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0,x.notice_date), 0)
          AND b.branch_name=y.branch_name
    ) cat,
    (   SELECT COUNT(C.car_no)
        FROM DB2.dbo.z_pat C
        WHERE DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0,c.notice_date), 0)
              = DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0,x.notice_date), 0)
          AND c.branch_name=y.branch_name
    ) pat
FROM DB1.dbo.Cars x
   , DB2.dbo.Branch Y
WHERE DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0,x.notice_date), 0)
      > '2011-01-01'
GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(10),x.notice_date,120)
       , DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0,x.notice_date), 0)
       , y.branch_name
```

Comment: Please format the query so it's a bit more readable. Try to get the external data into a local temp. table before making all calculations.

Comment: @ARB: You should by this time have learnt how to format your posts. They have been edited more than once by other people to improve their presentability, for your benefit no less than for others'. I think it's high time you started doing that yourself.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong formatting ..I tried to format but i cudn't ..so i was thinking somebody got the job of formatting.. I ll do the proper format from now on.. . @Siva. I am using sql server 2008

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve with all the DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0,x.notice_date), 0) code?

Comment: The column is actually datetime..so i am making datetime as 2011-01-01 00:00:00.. So all the datetimes of samedates fall under single date category

Answer (score 1):

This might help. Give it a try.

```
SELECT          
DISTINCT        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), car.notice_date, 120) AS NoticeDate
            ,   brc.branch_name
            ,   COUNT(CASE WHEN car.status = 'broken'   AND car.branch_name = brc.branch_name   THEN 1 END) Broken
            ,   COUNT(CASE WHEN car.status = 'Lote'     AND car.branch_name = brc.branch_name   THEN 1 END) Lost
            ,   mat.mat_count
            ,   cat.cat_count
            ,   pat.pat_count
FROM            DB1.dbo.Cars        car
            ,   DB2.dbo.Branch      brc
CROSS APPLY     (   
                    SELECT  COUNT(mat.car_no)   mat_count
                    FROM    DB2.dbo.z_mat       mat
                    WHERE   DATEDIFF(d, mat.notice_date, car.notice_date) = 0
                    AND     mat.branch_name     = brc.branch_name
                ) mat
CROSS APPLY     (   
                    SELECT  COUNT(cat.car_no)   cat_count
                    FROM    DB2.dbo.z_cat       cat
                    WHERE   DATEDIFF(d, cat.notice_date, car.notice_date) = 0
                    AND     cat.branch_name     = brc.branch_name
                ) cat
CROSS APPLY     (   
                    SELECT  COUNT(pat.car_no)   pat_count
                    FROM    DB2.dbo.z_pat       pat
                    WHERE   DATEDIFF(d, pat.notice_date, car.notice_date) = 0
                    AND     pat.branch_name     = brc.branch_name
                ) pat
WHERE           car.notice_date > '2011-01-01'
GROUP BY        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), car.notice_date, 120)
            ,   brc.branch_name
```

Comment: I'm not sure if `DATEDIFF(d, '2011-01-01', car.notice_date) > 0` uses the index of `car.notice_date`. The query may benefit from witing that as `car.notice_date > '2011-01-01'` (I suppose `Cars.notice_date` is of `DATE` type.)

Comment: @Siva: Thanks . It is now taking 4.20 mins.. u hv joined 2 tables cars and Branch on branch_name.. but what i want is all notice_date and all branch... I want distinct notice_date,Branch_name from cars,Branch...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10),x.notice_date,120) Date,Y.branch_name,
COUNT(case when x.status='broken' then 1 end) Broken,
COUNT(case when x.type='Lote' then 1 end) Lost,
SUM(mat) mat, SUM(cat) cat,SUM(pat) pat
 FROM DB1.dbo.Cars x 
      JOIN DB2.dbo.Branch Y ON x.branch_name=y.branch_name
      -- group by date and branch name for z_mat table
      LEFT JOIN (select COUNT(car_no) mat,branch_name,DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day,notice_date), 0)) notice_date from DB2.dbo.z_mat GROUP BY branch_name,DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day,notice_date), 0)) AS a
          ON a.branch_name = y.branch_name AND DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0,x.notice_date), 0) = a.notice_date
      -- group by date and branch name for z_cat table    
      LEFT JOIN (select COUNT(car_no) cat,branch_name,DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day,notice_date), 0)) notice_date from DB2.dbo.z_cat GROUP BY branch_name,DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day,notice_date), 0)) AS b
          ON b.branch_name = y.branch_name AND DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0,x.notice_date), 0) = b.notice_date
      -- group by date and branch name for z_pat table        
     LEFT JOIN (select COUNT(car_no) pat,branch_name,DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day,notice_date), 0)) notice_date from DB2.dbo.z_pat GROUP BY branch_name,DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day,notice_date), 0)) AS c
          ON c.branch_name = y.branch_name AND DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0,x.notice_date), 0) = c.notice_date 
WHERE DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0,x.notice_date), 0)>'2011-01-01' 
GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(10),x.notice_date,120),DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0,x.notice_date), 0),y.branch_name
```

Comment: Try also using tablename.notice_date instead of CONVERT(varchar(10),x.notice_date,120). It may cancel a use of index on notice_date if it exists

Comment: Updated to use left join's for subquery's